# How do I keep a secondary GET variable, when updating the form in HTML

Tags: php, html, forms, search, get

I'm currently developing a site where I have a search function. I want to add a secondary GET variable as a filter when searching. The best way I can think of doing this, is with a secondary GET variable, but I can't get it to keep the secondary variable.

When opening the search site the URL looks like this:
`example.com/search?search=example&secondary_variable=1`

But when updating the formular, the secondary variable goes away:
`example.com/search?search=example`

What can I do to keep it? I use HTML, JavaScript & PHP.

Comment: In your `<form>`, add a hidden field that contains your secondary variable, and its value.  This field is build from the index and value found in $_GET.  When the form is submitted, it will pick it up and add it in the URL. See https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Comment: How are you creating the URL? Why can't you copy the secondary variable into it? Show your code.

Comment: `$url = 'example.com/search?' + http_build_query($_GET);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would create `<input>` tags of type `hidden` and store the `search` and `secondary_variable` parameter's in it for PHP, then modify them as you need and do the search magic after the forum is submitted.

Example:
Main file:

```php
<form action="submit.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="secondary_variable" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['secondary_variable']); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="search">
</form>
```

submit.php

```php
<?php
    $search = htmlspecialchars($_GET['search']);
    $secondary_variable = htmlspecialchars($_GET['secondary_variable']);
    
    //// Do some PHP magic here, or just use the header() function to redirect the user to the search page
    header('Location: http://example.com/search?search='.$search.'&secondary_variable='.$secondary_variable);
?>
```